# what "bend the hostile environment of Mars for human habitation" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning, figurative-language

I found out this phrase in the TEDx talk "Let's not use Mars as a backup planet". As I was searching in the dictionaries, I understood the basic meaning of the verb which is "make curved" but I didn't found the figurative meaning.

Any comment would be useful.

Comment: Please see [**bend**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bend) **3.0** Force or be forced to submit, and **3.1** Interpret or modify (a rule) to suit someone.

Answer (score 2):

I could wish you nhad supplied a link or a longer quote for fuller context, but the meanign is probably "deform", "distort", or "modify". In short the meaning is "change the hostile environment of Mars, so as to permit human habitation" with a probable implication that such change is a negative or undesirable thing.

Comment: Addition to David's good response: the phrase "bend or break" has a long history in English, suggesting that there are things you can adapt, or not.  The suggestion is sometimes that there is no "middle ground".  For something like Mars, you might also think about the process of (say) bending metal, which requires some industrial effort and skill -- just like dealing with alien planets.